# React update nested objects with input name

Tags: reactjs, input, state, nested-object

Lets imagine we have the following state:

```
const [sample,setSample] = useState({
    key:{
        value:'',
        otherValue:''
    }
});
```

Now we all know that if we use name=key on an input like this:

```
<input name="key" value={key} .../>
```

we can change the "key" property with:

```
 set sample({...sample,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
```

But I was wondering, could we expand this a bit further to be used with nested state.
What if we use name=key.value to change the "value" or "otherValue" property under "key" like this:

```
<input name="key.value" value={key.value} .../>
```

But in this case, it just creates a key with the name "key.value" to the state, which is not what we want.

I found this method [what is the best way to setState which contains nested Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892742/what-is-the-best-way-to-setstate-which-contains-nested-object) but I found that solution to be a little brute force and not that elegant.

Is there any way to make this work without brute forcing it? (What if nesting values could vary?)

Comment: Will you please show some more complete code to illustrate your question more precisely? What do you mean by `name=key` or `name=key.value`? Where would this appear in your code? And what is "otherValue"? For tips on creating a good code example, see [mcve].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your insight, I updated the post to have a more meaningful code example.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. I assume you mean `setSample(...)` instead of `set sample(...)`. Where does this line of code appear?

Comment: If I understand your question, you could do something like `<input name={sample.key.name} value={sample.key.value}/>` assuming that there is a `name` key in the nested object.

Comment: You should also look at `Object.keys()` which gives you a list of keys in your object. This might be very useful depending on your use case. Again, we need a more detailed example in order to help more.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where you found a potential code solution to a feature you want in your app. It will help a lot if you explain the original problem you were trying to solve and we can help more from there.

Comment: Hello can you create a sample please ? 
However you can try with name={[key,value]}

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can try react-hook-form to resolve your problem.

See some exemple here to use register with nested : https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register